# jQuery UI validation plugin adds class 'valid' to elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

I am using jquery ui validation plugin. I am validating only few fields(input elements) but when form is validated class 'valid' is being added to other input elements(in jqgrid) that I am not validating. And this applies only to those input's in jqgrid that were edited(or focus in-blur). The problem is I have to iterate over each input in jqgrid based on class. So is there a way to avoid this unnecessary 'valid' class being added to elements even though they have to be not validated by ui-validate plugin?

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle showing the problem?

Comment: Your description and tags are all over the place.  First, there is no such thing as "jquery ui validation plugin".  Second, the [tag:jquery-validation-engine] tag and the [tag:jquery-validate] tag are for two totally unrelated plugins.  If you're using jQuery Validate, then you can change the `valid` class to anything you want.  Show your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the [jQuery Validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), use the `validClass` option to set the class to something different than `valid`.  By default, it's `valid`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({
        // other options & rules,
        validClass: "myValidClass"
    });

});
```

See documentation:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions